# Mount partition in VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, mount, linux-mint

I have the following problem I have edited the fstab to mount a partition with CIFS network.

```
//192.168.0.1/sharefile /home/user/sharefile/ cifs username=linux,password=12345678,user=user,uid=1001,gid=1000,rw,auto,_netdev,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Install linux mint on a computer to be able to use it remotely I need a VPN connection.
But at the time of starting the computer the CIFS partition cannot be mounted, so I must connect via VPN first and then run the command 'sudo mount -a' and the partition mount.

I dont have enougt experencia in Linux but there is the possibiity to create a executable on the desktop and the user click that and ejecuted commands like 'sudo mount -a'.

To connect by VPN I import a Linux.ovpn file and then connect like in the picture

[image]

I hope I explain well greetings.

Comment: Use OpenVPN to run a command after the VPN is established. See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398036/running-a-command-after-my-openvpn-client-connects

Comment: You probably want `noauto` (and maybe `nofail` as well) for the fstab entry and `mount /home/user/sharefile/` for the above.

Comment: @Appleoddity I do not understand much the post, sorry I do not understand much unix, but from the client side I must add `script-security 2
up / path / to / script.sh` I create 2 user one Linux is the administrador and the user is user for the pc